# MVC3 Weird behavior of ActionLink with HTML 5 Data- attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html

When I use this helper method to create a link, the data attribute shows up correctly in HTML code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Test", "Index", null, new { data_something = "123" })
```

The HTML is correct:

```
<a data-something="123" href="/">Test</a>
```

When I use the following overload of the `ActionLink` method (I use the T4MVC script, http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC), the data attribute contains an underscore instead of a dash:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Test", MVC.Home.Index(), new { data_something = "123" })
```

The HTML is incorrect:

```
<a data_something="123" href="/">Test</a>
```

Is this a know bug or a feature? I searched the bugtracker (http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic) but was not able to find a corresponding issue.

The following overload is working again, but I don't like to create Dictonaries all the time:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Test", MVC.Home.Index(), new Dictionary<string, object> { 
       { "data-something", "123" }
    })
```

Comment: Seems to be an issue of the T4MVC template: A patch already exists:http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/Forks/chebureg/T4MVCupdate/contribution/1538#

Answer (score 0):

for data attribute use `@data_something="123"` like

```
@Html.ActionLink("Test link",
                  MVC.Home.Index(),
                  new {controller="Home"}},new {@data_something="123"})
```

the above code should output

```
<a href="/Home/Index/" data-something="123">Test Link></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's just another workaround. Why are htmlAttributes processed differently in the various overloads of ActionLink?

Comment: @Daniel yes that is a work around because it seems like the `-` has been reserved so you have to use `_` instead

Comment: I don't like to use a workaround. I think I will open a ticket.